# problems calling the Batch function

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

I am using version 7.0.3-alpha  with facebook ver 2.2.
I experience a lot of problems when calling the batch function with post request.
the starnge thing is that it sometimes work when the number of parameters in the arry are 1 or 2. 
the exception i get is (GraphBatchException - #0) Batch parameter must be a JSON array.

an example code where i try to create several campaigns groups under qan account

```
    public void Test_UploadCampaigns_GroupBatch()
    {
        var arr = new FacebookBatchParameter[10]; 
        var fbbp = new FacebookBatchParameter();
        var postArgs = new Dictionary<string, object>();
        postArgs["name"] = "TestBatch";
        postArgs["objective"] = "WEBSITE_CONVERSIONS";
        postArgs["campaign_group_status"] = "ACTIVE";
        postArgs["buying_type"] = "AUCTION";
        fbbp.Path = "act_XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" + "/" + "adcampaign_groups/";
        fbbp.HttpMethod = HttpMethod.Post;
        fbbp.Parameters = postArgs;
        arr[0] = fbbp;
        arr[1] = fbbp;
        arr[2] = fbbp;
        arr[3] = fbbp;
        arr[4] = fbbp;
        arr[5] = fbbp;
        arr[6] = fbbp;
        arr[7] = fbbp;
        arr[8] = fbbp;
        arr[9] = fbbp;
        var t = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(arr);
        var result = TheParams.Fbw.fb.Batch(arr);
        var resultList = (IList<object>)result;
```

i checked the json i send and it looks fine. i could not find any reference for this exception in facebook . well i am totaly confused
Thanks in advance for your assitace.